# C cross-platform toolkit

Tags: c, cross-platform, glib

I'm looking for a "core" C cross-platform toolbox, because I need lots of "useful" functions (read/write ini files, network routines, arrays, lists...)

I was thinking about GLib, may be Qt (the core part) but I would appreciate a pure "C" stuff

Comment: There are plenty of possibilities out there, your question has a broad answer set. If you don't have any reason to not use GLib, then use it. You could also browse www.freecode.com and find tens of alternatives.

Comment: Agree, but I can wrap C++. Anyway, ANSI C remains the better approach (in my case)

Answer (score 1):

I think [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) is a fantastic choice, but it's perhaps somewhat less widely scoped than what you're after, there is no networking in glib as far as I know.

For that, you need to add [GIO](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/) from the same family of libraries.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/) (APR) may be the solution you are looking for. It is used, among other projects, for the Apache http server and Subversion.

Answer (score 1):

I think glib is great. It comes with a great deal of core algorithms and data types. There are many libraries build around GLib and GObject.  You have indeed GIO for all kinds of different input and output on files, over network etc (will remind you a bit of the Java like IO operations), and you gtk for Gui applications. All These libraries were designed with portability in mind and extendibility to other languages (eg. python, perl etc). But learn to use GOjbect as well, because the best work comes from using these libraries ( http://www.gtk.org/documentation.php ) together.